# Rails 3 ActiveRecord .skip_callback thread safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback, thread-safety

Is this code thread safe?

```
MyModel.skip_callback(:save, :before, :my_callback)
my_model_instance.update_attributes(attributes)
MyModel.set_callback(:save, :before, :my_callback)
```

Can i safely use it to avoid retrigger the same callback recursively?

Here is an example

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save  :update_blog_theme, :if => :active_theme_id_changed?

  # ...

  private

  def update_blog_theme

    # Reuses a previously used BlogTheme or creates a new one
    blog_theme = BlogTheme.find_by_theme_id_and_blog_id(
                      self.active_theme_id, 
                      self.id)

    blog_theme ||= BlogTheme.create!( 
                     :theme_id => active_theme_id, 
                     :blog_id => self.id )

    Blog.skip_callback(:save, :after, :update_blog_theme)
    self.update_attributes!(:active_blog_theme_id => blog_theme.id) 
    Blog.set_callback(:save, :after, :update_blog_theme)

  end

end
```

Comment: Seems hacky, why can't you use before_save or before_create?

Comment: no requirements here, i'm not using this code, and perhaps i'll never do, but i've found this solution around the internet and asked myself if it was safe to use in multithreading

Comment: Edited the question body with a real life example

Answer (score 9):

`skip_callback` and `set_callback` are NOT thread safe. I was able to confirm this while trying to create some records within sidekiq (a threaded async job processor). As soon as I re-enable the callbacks, there is a race condition that results in callbacks being called. If I comment the callback re-activation code, there are no issues.

I have found a number of possible solutions to the issue including two gems:

- the 'sneaky-save' gem
- the 'skip_activerecord_callbacks' gem

The sneaky-save gem seems to be the most straight-forward and intention-revealing option here. The gem essentially bypasses the ActiveRecord persistence methods and executes straight sql.

It is also the only one that I can confidently say is thread-safe. It is also a very small and understandable gem. The downside is that it does not call validations. Thus you would need to call validations yourself.

Anand A. Bait put together a great rundown on a number options. I am skeptical that all five options are threadsafe. The two gems mentioned above are listed along with other *possible* options in Anand's post here: http://www.allerin.com/blog/save-an-object-skipping-callbacks-in-rails-3-application/