# Rails - shall I set_callbacks after skip_callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, database-migration, rails-migrations

In a migration I disable callbacks like:

```
class AlignUserAreaToCountry < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    # disable the after_initialize :_set_defaults callback
    User.skip_callback(:initialize, :after, :_set_defaults)
    ...
  end
end
```

Shall I call `User.set_callback(...)` at the end of the same `up` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I remember, you do need to re-enable the callbacks with `set_callback`. Thankfully, you can pass a block to `skip_callback` and run your migration so you don't need to do explicitly:

```
User.skip_callback(:initialize, :after, :_set_defaults) do 
  add_column :users, :first_name, :string
end
```

More info in ActiveSupport::Callbacks::ClassMethods, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html

**However, this solution is not thread-safe.** I would recommend using a virtual attribute (such as dont_apply_callbacks) and if its presence exists, skip the desired callbacks.

Comment: Using a virtual attribute would be the only way to ensure that the callbacks are still being fired for anything that's happening outside of your migration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723816/rails-3-activerecord-skip-callback-thread-safety is still relevant, though dated and related to Rails 3.